# How do I configure PostgreSQL or MySQL to set up a database with Sphinx?

Tags: mysql, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I really need help installing Sphinx and getting it going.

I'm on rails 3 and I'm following these set of directions: http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/quickstart.html to install Sphinx.

Thinking Sphinx was easy to install since it's a gem.  However, the guide says I need to have both Sphinx **and** Thinking Sphinx installed to get started (Is this true?).  I checked Ryan Bates' railscast for Thinking Sphinx and he only installed the plugin and got started immediately.

Anyways, I installed Sphinx via MacPorts and here's proof:

```
...
  --->  Configuring mysql5
  --->  Building mysql5
  --->  Staging mysql5 into destroot
  --->  Installing mysql5 @5.1.57_0
   The MySQL client has been installed.

...

--->  Installing sphinx @0.9.9_0+mysql5
--->  Activating sphinx @0.9.9_0+mysql5
--->  Cleaning sphinx
```

It automatically configured Sphinx with mysql5.  I have both mySQL and POSTgreSQL.

Now the next step was to `rake thinking_sphinx:index` after setting up an index in my user model which looks like this:

```
  define_index do
   indexes year
   indexes major
   indexes books_buy
   indexes books_sell
   indexes facebook
   indexes restaurants
   indexes interests

   end
```

However, `rake thinking_sphinx:index` gave me this:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'thinking_sphnix:index'
```

and then

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- sqlite3
```

So I figured my database was configured on sqlite3 still.  So I switched the gem to mySQL and edited my database.yml file to look like this:

```
# Switched over to mysql

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
development:
  adapter: mysql5
  encoding: utf8
  database: sphinx_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

test:
  adapter: mysql5
  encoding: utf8
  database: sphinx_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql5
  encoding: utf8
  database: sphinx_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

and I got these errors:

```
rake aborted!
Please install the mysql5 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql5-adapter` (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/mysql5_adapter)
```

and

```
    ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-mysql5-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter, activerecord-nulldb-adapter, activerecord-odbc-adapter, activerecord-jdbc-adapter, activerecord-postgis-adapter
Tony-Ngs-MacBook-Air:sample_app TonyNg$ gem install activerecord-nulldb-adapter
```

Any tips would be generous and helpful.  Would also be willing to switch to PostgreSQL if help lead provided. Thanks!

Comment: So you decided to ignore the error message which tells you exactly what to do? "**Please install the mysql5 adapter**: `gem install activerecord-mysql5-adapter`"

Comment: No, I tried that too and got: `ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-mysql5-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter, activerecord-nulldb-adapter, activerecord-odbc-adapter, activerecord-jdbc-adapter, activerecord-postgis-adapter
`

Comment: first off, sphinx only supports mysql and postgresql, not sqlite3. also, to verify if you installed Sphinx do you have "searchd" in your path? Thats the sphinx search daemon. It sounds like you need to create your development MySQL db, which you need to do via the mysql prompt.

Comment: @Cody Caughlan.  Yes I do have "searchd" under opt/local/bin.  And I just created a development MySQL db.  And yes, I do understand that sphinx only supports those two options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put either `mysql` or `mysql2` as your adapter - and include either gem (same names as the adapters) in your Gemfile. I recommend mysql2, as it's actively maintained - but keep in mind if you're using Rails 3.0.x, then you must use a 0.2.x release of mysql2. If you're on Rails 3.1, then use mysql2 0.3.x.

Comment: Awesome tip! That was it! I really do appreciate the help.  The gemfile version and adapter part really confused me.