# How do I Install Thinking Sphinx on windows 7 with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am lost on how to install Sphinx in the correct way to get it running with my Rails application on a Windows 7 64x machine. I followed this thread: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=29437 where it says to set the PATH Variable but that did not work, it only caused my git bash path to get screwed up and disable ruby commands in it.

When I start the rails server I get:

```
Sphinx cannot be found on your system. You may need to configure the following
settings in your config/sphinx.yml file:
  * bin_path
  * searchd_binary_name
  * indexer_binary_name


For more information, read the documentation:
http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/advanced_config.html
```

My directory location is **C:/Sphinx**

But the config file `sphinx.yml` file doesn't exist when I download the binary > http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/beta/

```
Win32 binaries w/MySQL+PgSQL+libstemmer+id64 support    2.0.1-beta  5.6M
```

Did anyone figure out how to get this working?

UPDATE 1:

Made the file sphinx.yml inside of my config/ folder of my Rails application and put this in their so far but still no luck:

**config/sphinx.yml**

```
    development:
       bin_path: "c:/Sphinx/bin"
```

UPDATE 2:

OK I reinstalled it and now get this error:

```
Generating Configuration to C:/myapp/config/development.sphinx.conf
rake aborted!
Invalid Database Adapter: Sphinx only supports MySQL and PostgreSQL, not ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Adapter
```

**So in order to run Thinking Sphinx I have to have MySql or PostgreSQL in development and not SQLite3?**

Comment: sphinx.yml, is not part of sphinx(search) itself. I guess it must be part of thinkingsphinx.

Comment: @barryhunter Ah I see, the place in my application, forgot! let me see if I can do this. I am guessing I have to make the file.

Comment: is C:\Sphinx in your PATH? (does `where searchd` returns you the path to the executable?) As long `searchd.exe` and `indexer.exe` are in the PATH (`SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Sphinx`) things should work.

Comment: @LuisLavena I just go to my command prompt and type in SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Sphinx? If so, I did that and still no good.

Comment: Just to confirm: it is Sphinx itself (not Thinking Sphinx) that does not work with SQLite - hence the need to use either MySQL or PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you download MySQL because yes, it does not work with SQlite3 Database. Take a at these questions:

[How do I configure PostgreSQL or MySQL to set up a database with Sphinx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369416/how-do-i-configure-postgresql-or-mysql-to-set-up-a-database-with-sphinx)

[How to install Ruby on Rails with mysql and get it working, a step by step guide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996834/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-mysql-and-get-it-working-a-step-by-step-guide)